# Multiple Multiplart Image Upload ENOENT open failed error in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

I m trying to upload Multipart Multiple Image Upload in Retrofit,but it shows response failure error like that **[/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Images/abc.jpg,/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Images/abcd.jpg] open failed; ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

I followed this tutorial...https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server

I used this Library for Image Picker...https://github.com/myinnos/AwesomeImagePicker

Activity.java :

```
private void ImageChooser(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ConstantsCustomGallery.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT,5); // set limit for image selection
    startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantsCustomGallery.REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == ConstantsCustomGallery.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ArrayList<images> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ConstantsCustomGallery.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

        ArrayList<String> imagelist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(i).path));
            String filePath = getRealPathFromURIPath(uri, WorkerAddPhotosActivity.this);
            imagelist.add(filePath);
        }
           LoadWorkerInquiry(images)
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURIPath(Uri contentURI, Activity activity) {
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
} 

public void LoadWorkerInquiry(ArrayList<String> image) {
    ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
    List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < image.size(); index++) {
        File file = new File(image.toString());
        RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        parts.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), surveyBody));
    }

    Call<WorkerImageUpload> call = getResponse.uploadImages(parts);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<WorkerImageUpload>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WorkerImageUpload> call, retrofit2.Response<WorkerImageUpload> response) {
            WorkerImageUpload serverResponse = response.body();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WorkerImageUpload> call, Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof IOException) {
                Error("Timeout",t.getMessage());
            }
            else if (t instanceof IllegalStateException) {
                Error("ConversionError",t.getMessage());
            } else {
                Error("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Api Interface :

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/***")
Call<WorkerImageUpload> uploadImages(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> Image);
```

Comment: post your upload code here

Comment: Please, See code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access WhatsApp internal storage which is forbidden without specifically granted access.

Try to access files in your app storage. This documentation will be useful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I am also trying some Camera,ScreenShot,etc images but the result is same